# i write code in es6 and used call method but additional arguments are not passing it shows undefined

Tags: javascript

```
const  msg1 = {
    fname:'Divyesh',
    lname:'Patel',
}
const person = {
 fullname : function(city,num)
    {
        return this.fname+ " " + this.lname+" "+ this.city +" "+ this.num ;       
    }
}
console.log(person.fullname.call(msg1,"Surat","972737"));
```

output :
Divyesh Patel undefined undefined

i write code in es6 and used call method but additional arguments are not passing it shows undefined

Comment: arguments are not "accessed" using `this` - so, `.... ,city +" "+ num` instead - this is no different to ES5, so your usage of ES6 in the question is irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

```
 const msg1 = {
      fname: 'Divyesh',
      lname: 'Patel',
    }
    const person = {
      fullname: function (city, num) {
        return this.fname + " " + this.lname + " " + city + " " + num;
      }
    }
    console.log(person.fullname.call(msg1, "Surat", "972737"));
```